# TypeScript compiler api - generate static nested class

Tags: typescript, code-generation

Nested static classes in TypeScript can be declared like the following

```
export class Foo {
    public static readonly Bar = class {
        public static readonly FooBar: string = 'FooBar';
    }
}
```

When using the function `createClassDeclaration` from the TypeScript compiler api to generate a static class I receive the following that doesn't compile

```
export class Foo {
    public static readonly class Bar {
        public static readonly FooBar: string = 'FooBar';
    }
}
```

I run my generation script with ts-node.
Here my compilerOptions

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "ESNext",
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true
}
```

So my question is, how can I create a static class like shown in the first code example above?

Comment: what's your ts compiler version?

Comment: The version is 4.5.5